# SolarThermalCollectors, HotWaterTank and GroundSourceHeatExchanger Model

Tags: modelica, dymola

In this model, I want to simulate regarding changed in cirtain wheather conditions (e.g. solar radiation in a whole year), solar thermal collectors heat first the hot water tank. After hot water tank reaches to its max. allowable temperature, the excessive heat which comes from the solar collectors will be released to the ground. To simulate heat release, I use Bore hole single U-tube model with additional heat port. If the excessive heat is not released to the ground, the medium temperature(e.g. water) exceeds the allowable temperature of solar collectors which is 130 Celcius.
With which component should I connect the heat port of ground source heat exchanger, in order to simulate the ground which takes heat from the system and how much heat should I take out from the system?

[SolarThermalConnectors connected with HotwaterTank and BoreHole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjK7n.png)

Answer (score 0):

Unless the actual physical system is designed as you describe it, I would design it differently:

The hot water tank should *decouple* heat production and consumption — **conceptually** shown in the figure below.

[image]

The solar collector  circulation pump controls the collector outlet temperature so that only hot water at the right temperature (e.g. 90 °C) is stored (in order to maintain a "sharp" thermocline). When the storage tank is almost full, energy-wise (e.g. 90 %), the borehole circulation pump should maintain the energy level by circulating water through the borehole exchanging heat with a fixed low ground temperature.

Comment: I built the concept which you suggested. I built also the concept that I described in my question. Although I do not receive any error by checking process, during simulation process i am receiving for both concepts  the same error message _Failed to expand the variable borHol.borFieDat.conDat.cooBor and its definition equation: borHol.borFieDat.conDat.cooBor_. I am uploading the necessary data for "Borefield parameters" from `InsertComponentReferences_FilDat_soiDat_ConDat`.